# Asynchronous OR Synchronous Loading is better?

Tags: facebook, asynchronous, facebook-javascript-sdk

Found on JavaScript SDK
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

```
    "...
    Asynchronous Loading
    --------------------------------
    This code loads the SDK asynchronously so it does not block loading other
 elements of your page. This is particularly important to **ensure fast page 
loads for users and SEO robots**.

    Synchronous Loading
    --------------------------------
    It is possible to load the SDK synchronously which may be useful for 
debugging, but this method is not recommended for typical use. Synchronous
operations will block the web page, resulting in worse performance and a 
slower user experience. This **may also negatively impact SEO due to the 
increased slowness perceived by robots and crawler**s. ..."
```

So, which one of these statements is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are.

For debugging Sync is good.

For production code Async is better.